# Excel countif doesn't work on range denoted by {}

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a formula that returns values in a set such as this:

```
{0;0;0;9;7;6;0;0;0}
```

If I use

```
COUNTIF({0;0;0;9;7;6;0;0;0};0)
```

I get the error that Excel gives a notification: A problem is found with your formula. How can I solve this to be able to count the zeros.

Answer (score 6):

COUNTIF requires a range not an array. To use an array one would need to switch to an array type formula like SUMPRODUCT:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--({0;0;0;9;7;6;0;0;0}=0))
```

[image]